# hasNext not working on collection in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have following code in javascript which retrieves two rows:

```
 var raceCursor = RacesCollection.find({eventId: "e1"});
    var race;
    while(raceCursor.hasNext()){
    race = raceCursor.next();                   
    console.log(race.raceName);
    }
```

Seems nothing wrong with it, but it shows :

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasNext'` in the javascript console.

What I am missing here?

Do the MongoDB methods requires special imports in javascript, in order to be used on the collections??

The Collection is:

```
RacesCollection  = new Meteor.Collection("RacesCollection");
RacesCollection.insert({raceId:"r1", eventId:"e1", raceName:"Moto race 1", status:"statusDetail"});
RacesCollection.insert({raceId:"r2", eventId:"e1", raceName:"Moto race 2", status:"statusDetail"});
```

Any recommendation will be appriciated. thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor) the proper way to iterate a cursor is `cursor.forEach()`. Also cursors don't have `hasNext()` or `next()` methods.

So in your case it should read:

```
var raceCursor = RacesCollection.find({eventId: "e1"});

raceCursor.forEach(function(race) {
    console.log(race.raceName);    
});
```

Comment: I wonder why the mongodb documentation shows an example with cursor.hasNext() and cursor.next(). http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: @Rafael that's mongo cursor, not meteor cursor