# Recursion mongodb: Delete the Parent Directory along with the Children's Catalogs

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to remove in collections the parent's catalog with children's catalogs and with the documents in the children's catalogs.

I want to delete the partent directory with id: "1" and with it children's directories id: "2,3" and children's catalogs of children id: "4".

`{
  '_id': '1',
   'name': 'parent',
  'idCatalog': 'null',
},
{
  '_id': '2',
  'name': 'B',
  'idCatalog': '1',
},
{
  '_id': '3',
  'name': 'C',
  'idCatalog': '1',
},
{
  '_id': '4',
  'name': 'D',
  'idCatalog': '2',
}`

--- CATALOG PARENT   <--- I am removing it

-------- CATALOG A

------------- document A1

------------- document A2

-------- CATALOG B

-------- document B1

CATALOG PARTENT {_id:"CATALOG PARTENT"}

-- CATALOG A {_id:"KATALOG A", idCatalog: "CATALOG PARTENT"}

---- document A1 {_id: "document A1", idCatalog: "CATALOG A" }

---- document A2 {_id: "document A2", idCatalog: "CATALOG A" }

-- CATALOG B {_id:"CATALOG B", idCatalog: "CATALOG PARTENT"}

---- document B1 {_id:"document B1", idCatalog: "CATALOG B"}

Comment: Please provide example data from your collection and a result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your data model you can remove a catalog with its children in two steps. First, you find ids of all children of the root catalog:

```
function getIdsRecursively(parentId, result) {
  result.push(parentId);
  var children = db.tree.find({idCatalog: parentId});
  while (children.hasNext()) {
    var id = children.next()._id;
    getIdsRecursively(id, result)
  }
}
var ids = [];
getIdsRecursively('1', ids);
```

Second, you remove catalogs with those ids:

```
db.catalogs.remove({_id: {$in: ids}});
```

Notice that the *find* query is run multiple times. If you want to avoid this you probably should use more advanced document structure to model the catalogs hierarchy. For example, check [materialized paths](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) in the mongodb documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I use "Meteor.js" and receives the error "children.hasNext is not a function". I think I've found a solution but I can not connect it with your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969604/hasnext-not-working-on-collection-in-javascript/12969928#12969928

Comment: @samuraijack According to the post you've mentioned above you have to use forEach function, that accepts a function as an argument and applies it to every document. So you just need to put the code that is inside the _while_ loop into a function and pass it to the forEach function call like so:
`function getIdsRecursively(parentId, result) {
  result.push(parentId);
  var children = db.tree.find({idCatalog: parentId});
  children.forEach(function(child) {
    var id = child._id;
    getIdsRecursively(id, result)
  });
}`